# How to send video stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, httpserver

I am trying to develop [DroidCam](https://www.dev47apps.com/) like app where phone camera can be used as webcam in desktops. but i am struggling to send live video

I tried to start Server like this

```
Future<void> _startServer() async {
    setState(() {
      _statusText = "Starting server on Port: 4444";
    });

    final interfaces = await NetworkInterface.list();
    _ipAddress = interfaces
        .where((interface) => interface.name == 'wlan0')
        .expand((interface) => interface.addresses)
        .firstWhere(
          (address) => address.type == InternetAddressType.IPv4,
          orElse: () => InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4,
        )
        .address;

    _server = await HttpServer.bind(
      _ipAddress,
      4444,
      shared: true,
    );

    debugPrint(
      "Server running on IP: ${_server?.address} on Port: ${_server?.port}",
    );

    await for (var request in _server!) {
      await _controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
      await _controller.prepareForVideoRecording();
      await _controller.startVideoRecording();

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      final video = await _controller.stopVideoRecording();
      final response = request.response;
      response.headers.contentType = ContentType("video", "mp4");
      response.add(await video.readAsBytes());
    }

    setState(() {
      _statusText =
          "Server running on IP: ${_server?.address} on Port: ${_server?.port}";
    });
  }
```

It was succes for recorded video, i tried `ImageStream` and `onAvailble` on `startVideoRecording` i cound not get it running